# How to create a order using sp-api-order-role in Amazon Marketplace

Tags: amazon-selling-partner-api, amazonsellercentral

I am currently working on integrating Amazon marketplace with Kibo. The current role access given to me is sp-api-orders-role. I am only able to fetch orders from Marketplace but not able to create or modify the orders. I am using /orders/v0/orders endpoint to send request. The orders section of selling-partner-api-model only include getOrders operation and no other operations. Am I missing something here or creating order is not possible through sp-api?

I have checked the official documentation and couldn't find it or I may have missed it since it's messy. Can anybody help me here?